# Определите, к каким частям речи относятся выделенные слова

Tags: морфология

1. Это вовсе не смешно.
2. Ты не умеешь смешно рассказывать.
3. Мне смешно это слушать.

Answer (score 1):

Одно замечание. В первом предложении слово *смешно* - не категория состояния. Это краткое прилагательное среднего рода (сравните: *Это не является смешным*; *Это не было смешным*). Является частью составного именного сказуемого.

Answer (score 0):

Во втором предложении это  наречие *(обозначает признак действия: рассказывать как? смешно)*. В 1 и 3 предложениях слово *смешно* имеет предикативное значение, здесь уместен термин *категория состояния* (или *предикативное наречие*). Категория состояния обычно управляет дателбным падежом (3-е предложение в предложенном примере): смешно *кому?* мне.

Comment: Да ,согласна. В первом предложении это краткое прилагательное.